# How do I reset my game in python using turtle after the user clicks a button?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am trying to make the code so that after both choices and the result is displayed an option appears to reset the game and try again, here is the code. This is the finishing detail for an assignment in school.

```
import turtle
import random
from turtle import *


# Create a screen
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Rock Paper Scissors")
screen.bgcolor("white")

# Decide computers choice
options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
computer_choice = random.choice(options)
# Load images for game options
rock_image = "rock.gif"
paper_image = "paper.gif"
scissors_image = "scissors.gif"
screen.addshape(rock_image)
screen.addshape(paper_image)
screen.addshape(scissors_image)

# Draw the game options
rock = turtle.Turtle()
rock.penup()
rock.goto(-400, 0)
rock.shape(rock_image)

paper = turtle.Turtle()
paper.penup()
paper.goto(0, 0)
paper.shape(paper_image)

scissors = turtle.Turtle()
scissors.penup()
scissors.goto(400, 0)
scissors.shape(scissors_image)

# Gameplay
def click(x, y):
    global choice
    if x < -200:
        choice = "rock"
    elif x > 200:
        choice = "scissors"
    else:
        choice = "paper"
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-200, 200)
    turtle.pendown()
    write(("You chose " + choice), font=("arial", 25, "italic" ))
    paper.hideturtle()
    rock.hideturtle()
    scissors.hideturtle()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(200, 200)
    turtle.pendown()
    write(("Computer chose " + computer_choice), font=("arial", 25, "italic" ))
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(100, -100)
    turtle.pendown()
    if computer_choice == choice:
        write("It's a tie!", font=("arial", 25, "italic" ))
    elif (computer_choice == "rock" and choice == "scissors") or \
     (computer_choice == "paper" and choice == "rock") or \
    (computer_choice == "scissors" and choice == "paper"):
        write("You lose!", font=("arial", 25, "italic" ))
    else:
        write("You win!", font=("arial", 25, "italic" ))




# Bind the click function to the screen
screen.onclick(click)

# Run the game
turtle.mainloop()
```

I tried implementing tkinter and this would create a separate window. This would cause problems as I went into full screen and then it would close the program without reopening it.